# Erroneous movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In one of my games, a snake like, I have a bug where the parts are supposed to be `0.125f` apart, but instead, the the distance between is the same as the distance between the first and second part.

[image]

What I believe to be the relevant code:

```
      using UnityEngine;
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SnakeHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float growTime = 5;
    private float moveSpeed;
    private Transform origin, prevPart = null;
    private List<GameObject> snakeBodyPartsList;
    public Mesh mesh;
    public Material material;
    private GameObject body, sphere;
    private RaycastHit hit;

    void Start()
    {
        sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        origin = new GameObject("SnakeHead Origin").transform;
        origin.parent = sphere.transform;
        transform.parent = origin;
        snakeBodyPartsList = new List<GameObject>();
        snakeBodyPartsList.Add(gameObject);
        StartCoroutine("addBodyPart");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
        foreach (GameObject part in snakeBodyPartsList)
        {
            moveSpeed = 30 + (snakeBodyPartsList.Count * 2.5f);
            if (part == gameObject)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
                {
                    var turnRate = Input.GetKey("a") ? -120 : 120;
                    part.transform.parent.Rotate(0, 0, turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                part.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, part.transform.position - sphere.transform.position);
                part.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.Cross(part.transform.parent.position - part.transform.position, part.transform.forward)) * part.transform.parent.rotation;
            }
            else
            {
                part.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(prevPart.transform.position, part.transform.position - sphere.transform.position);
                if (prevPart != null && Vector3.Distance(part.transform.position, prevPart.position) > 0.125f)
                {
                   // moveSpeed = moveSpeed + Vector3.Distance(part.transform.position, prevPart.position)* 100;
                    part.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.Cross(part.transform.parent.position - part.transform.position, -(prevPart.position - part.transform.position).normalized * 0.125f)) * part.transform.parent.rotation;
                }
            }
            returnToSurface(part);
            prevPart = part.transform;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator addBodyPart()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        body = createNewGameObject(body, "Body " + snakeBodyPartsList.Count, null, mesh, material, snakeBodyPartsList[snakeBodyPartsList.Count - 1].transform.position, Vector3.one / 10, true, true);
        snakeBodyPartsList.Add(body);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Mathf.Abs(growTime - 1));
        StartCoroutine("addBodyPart");
    }

    public GameObject createNewGameObject(GameObject uGO, string Name, Transform Parent, Mesh Mesh, Material Material, Vector3 Position, Vector3 localScale, bool needsOrigin, bool needscollider)
    {
        uGO = new GameObject(Name);
        if (needsOrigin)
        {
            origin = new GameObject("BodyPart Origin " + snakeBodyPartsList.Count).transform;
            origin.parent = sphere.transform;
            uGO.transform.parent = origin;
        }
        else
        {
            uGO.transform.parent = Parent;
        }
        uGO.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = Mesh;
        uGO.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = Material;
        uGO.transform.position = Position;
        uGO.transform.localScale = localScale;
        if (needscollider)
        {
            uGO.AddComponent<BoxCollider>().size = Vector3.one;
            uGO.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;
        }
        uGO.transform.forward = transform.forward;
        uGO.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        return uGO;
    }

    void returnToSurface(GameObject a)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(a.transform.position, sphere.transform.position) > 1.05)
        {
            while (Vector3.Distance(a.transform.position, sphere.transform.position) >= 1.045)
            {
                a.transform.position = new Vector3(a.transform.position.x, a.transform.position.y, a.transform.position.z - 0.001f);
            }
        }
        else if (Vector3.Distance(a.transform.position, sphere.transform.position) < 1.04)
        {
            while (Vector3.Distance(a.transform.position, sphere.transform.position) <= 1.045)
            {
                a.transform.position = new Vector3(a.transform.position.x, a.transform.position.y, a.transform.position.z + 0.001f);
            }
        }

    }
    public List<GameObject> getPartsList()
    {
        return snakeBodyPartsList;
    }
}
```

The movement of the block is probably badly coded because I am fairly new, any general tips and cleanup is generally welcome also. The blocks are moving around a sphere hence the perhaps odd seeming movement code.

Comment: So, just to get this straight ; the snake behaves like an oldschool snake game (just like on the old nokia 3310) , but on a sphere rather than on a plane?

Comment: pretty much, like i said, not planning to release it or anything, just some hobbyish work.

Comment: well this ain't "basic" movement. or at least not as basic as you thought.

Comment: okay bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong about this, but I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll post it as a reply for you to try:

Since your issue is only between the head and first body part, I'm imagining your issue is because there's no prevPart set on the first run (the gameObject body part isn't necessarily the first one to be checked in the foreach). You might want to try handling the first if-statement before the foreach, so that everything is guaranteed to be set up properly for the first run. You can keep the gameObject body part out of the list or handle the case with an if (like in this example).

Something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    moveSpeed = 30 + (snakeBodyPartsList.Count * 2.5f);

    // First update the head (gameObject)
    if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        var turnRate = Input.GetKey("a") ? -120 : 120;
        transform.parent.Rotate(0, 0, turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, transform.position - sphere.transform.position);
    transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.Cross(transform.parent.position - transform.position, transform.forward)) * transform.parent.rotation;
    returnToSurface(part);
    prevPart = part.transform;

    // Then update the body (snakeBodyPartsList)
    foreach (GameObject part in snakeBodyPartsList)
    {
        if (part != gameObject)
        {
            if (prevPart != null) // prevPart is already used here, so you might as well check it here instead of after the next line
            {
                part.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(prevPart.transform.position, part.transform.position - sphere.transform.position);
                if (Vector3.Distance(part.transform.position, prevPart.position) > 0.125f)
                {
                    part.transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.Cross(part.transform.parent.position - part.transform.position, -(prevPart.position - part.transform.position).normalized * 0.125f)) * part.transform.parent.rotation;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log('No prevPart in the snakeBodyPartsList foreach'); // EDIT: Might as well add something here just in case... :)
            }
            returnToSurface(part);
            prevPart = part.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Does that help?

PS: The movement code looks fine to me, but you might want to give your magic numbers variable names for clarity.

Comment: well, i understand the idea and agree with it, however this code when implemented. the exact same error still presents itself. ill update the code with the entire class, also the prevPart is initialized as null and therefore shouldn't interfere as such.

Answer (score 0):

So, this was solved by halving the move speed of the head during turning, havnt figure out why but the head moves faster than the body when turning causing it to pull away from the body parts. Thanks @Bruins from solent uni.